# spring boot serving image/jpeg gives gibberish

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to serve images from `mongodb GridFS`. My `Controller`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPhoto (@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("@getPhoto > ip of request: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + ", id: " + id);
    final InputStream inputStream = resourceService.getMediaResourceById(id);

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        log.error("@getPhoto > error with request for objectId: " + id, e);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**The result:**
[image: Bad photo]

This only happens using `Spring Boot`. as a test when using Spring and running the exact same code i'm getting:

[image: Good Picture]

Comment: You're never setting the content type of your response. How is the browser supposed to know that it's a JPEG image and not HTML?

Comment: I am...It's also not working when `produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE`

Comment: When you inspect the http response in your browser dev tools, do you see the header "Content-Type: image/jpeg"?

Comment: Content-Type → image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8... I have found the problem even though i don't really think it a problem. `response.flushBuffer()` does not work. when returning `ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), HttpStatus.OK)` everything is working... i wonder why

Comment: No idea either. But you shouldn't have to flush anything. Your web container will flush and close the ooutput stream for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing directly to a response is discouraged in controller methods for various reasons. You are essentially responsible for almost everything yourself. The preferred way is to return something that gets converted as needed.

You already use `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` now. But your source is a stream and you have to create an unnecessary byte array. You can use `Resource` instead that wraps all sorts of input streams, be it from files or already opened input streams.

```
InputStreamResource inputStream = new InputStreamResource(resourceService.getMediaResourceById(id));
return new ResponseEntity<>(inputStream, HttpStatus.OK);
```

or as of Spring 4.1

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(inputStream);
```

Please note that `produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE` doesn't actually set a content type. It's used for content negotiation.